# Why won't my stringify parse in an "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, stringify

```
const friends = ["john","peter","bob"];
localStorage.setItem("friends", JSON.stringify(friends));

const values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("friends"));
console.log(values[2]);
// console.log(values[1]);
// console.log(values[2]);

let fruits;
console.log(fruits);

if (localStorage.getItem('fruits')) {
 fruits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruits'));
}
else {
 fruits = [];
}

console.log(fruits);
fruits.push("apple");
fruits.push("orange");
localStorage.setItem("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));
```

Why will the first array behave properly in chrome where I can clearly check the console and application from dev.tools but when I try to make an empty array and push different values fx "apple" and "orange" I can't. My console says the error is in the "if" statement, but I don't understand why. Any thoughts?

Comment: *"console says the error is in the "if" statement"*: what exactly is the error message? What is the value returned by `localStorage.getItem('fruits')`? Can you print it and share it?

Comment: Don't know how to upload pictures here so put them into imgur.

https://imgur.com/8XixftA

https://imgur.com/4UszRIB

Comment: @c0d3r4ng0 Have you tried printing the value of `localStorage.getItem('fruits')` right before the problem line, it looks like the second character of the json is `u` and it should probably be a whitespace character or a quote.

Comment: VM4060:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at app.js:300

Comment: I will get on it!

Comment: @c0d3r4ng0, that image doesn't show the value I asked for, but the error message seems to indicate that `localStorage.getItem("fruits")` does not have a valid JSON value. Delete that entry first from localStorage and try from scratch.

Comment: console.log(localStorage.getItem(fruits)); returns : null

Comment: aha well it sets up the proper key "fruits" - but at value it says: " function stringify() { [native code] }"

Comment: is it possible that it can't initialize the JSON.parse because the key "fruits" is not defined yet not even as an array?

Comment: I believe the issue is fruits is undefined, and when fruits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruits')); tries to get run it tries to read "undefined" which then places "u" first. Any ideas how to circumvent that?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer lies in the quotes. JSON syntax is very strict and requires the use of double quotes. Change out all your single quotes in your if statement to double quotes and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: json is strict about the quotes, but this code isn't json. it's javascript.